# Taylor expansion need help understanding.

Tags: taylor-expansion, 3d, quadratics

I am at the moment reading a paper (SURF) and trying to understand what is happening here and how the things works as it does....

a non maximum supression is performed on the scale space representation of the image.  This give us a list the local maxima within +-1 neighborhood. These are den used here which i don't quite understand.

> The final step in localising the points involves interpolating the
>   nearby data to find the location in both space and scale to sub-pixel accuracy. This is done by fitting a 3D quadratic as proposed by Brown [3]. In order to do this we express the determinant of the Hessian function, H(x,y,$\sigma$), as a Taylor expansion up to quadratic terms centered at detected location. This is expressed as: $$H(\textbf{x}) = H \frac{\partial H^T}{\partial \textbf{x}}\textbf{x} + \frac{1}{2}\textbf{x}^T\frac{\partial^2 H}{\partial \textbf{x}^2}\textbf{x}$$
>   $\textbf{x}=(x,y)$

As I understand has there been made a taylor expansion based on some points.. is that even possible?

This is taken from this paper https://code.google.com/p/opensurf1/downloads/detail?name=opensurf.pdf

My question is this

Comment: The first derivative is the Jacobian matrix, the second derivative is the Hessian matrix.

Comment: I am a bit unsure on how the previous points are used to retrieve H(x).. and how come?

Comment: You take a local quadratic form where you approximate the values for the first and second partial derivatives using the neighboring points.

Comment: An illustration could be very helpful.. The points i have..  How are they used.. 
How are the neighboring points used in this case..